# where can I host my youtube flv file?

Tags: video

I'm building a flash application, in my application i need to stream an flv file. I tried hosting it on youtube, but I cannot get the flv file out of there, only the final swf file.

Where can I host my flv file, even for small payment so I can stream it in high quality?

Answer (score 2):

As another option Amazon Cloud Front has Flash Media Services.  I believe EC2 also has Flash Media Services you can bring online and they cover the license cost.  If you want something you can configure/manage yourself this might be a good option.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/
Streaming Distributions

Amazon CloudFront lets you create “streaming distributions” to deliver your rich media content in a different way than other Amazon CloudFront distributions. Streaming distributions deliver content to end users in real time – the end-users watch the bytes as they are delivered. To do this, streaming distributions use the Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) and several of its variants, instead of the HTTP or HTTPS protocols used by other Amazon CloudFront distributions. Amazon CloudFront uses Adobe’s Flash® Media Server to power its streaming distributions.